# How to find out the type of GameObject selected in the scene?

Tags: unity, gameobject

If I select some `GameObject` in the Unity, e.g. recently added `TextMeshProUGUI` inside the `Canvas`, where can I find out the type of selected game object?

In Inspector window, same as in Properties window (shown using context menu on the game object in Hierarcy window), I can see the name, tag, layout, etc. But where is the type?

I need to know the type to reference the game object in the code:

```
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;

public class Foo: MonoBehaviour
{
    public TextMeshProUGUI bar;
    ...
    public SomeMethod() => bar.text = "bla";
}
```

I've found [this topic](https://answers.unity.com/questions/365095/how-to-get-the-type-of-a-gameobject.html) which is rather confusing than helpful. Sure, all of game objects are inherited from `GameObject`, but to access `bar.text` I will need to know its type anyway.

From other point of view, I can look for components in Inspector and always use `bar.GetComponent<XYZ>()`, but similarly, `XYZ` is not shown in Inspector, I can see "TextMeshPro - Text (UI)" caption, which is not really `TMPro.TextMeshProUGUI` **type** I need to use in the code. So I have come to another question, how to get component type... Great isn't it?

I am likely missing something obvious. Am I the first asking this question?

Comment: Your link explains it relatively well, maybe you haven't fully figured out what GameObjects and what components are. GameObjects are always just GameObjects, you can look at them as simply a bucket holding components of different types (like TextMeshPro ones, or MonoBehaviours that you write).

Comment: After reading answers, I figured out I should be looking for a component type, rather than game object type (was my confusion). @Nikaas, I am looking for a fastest way to do following: select object in scene, find the underlying type to reference its component, which property I am going to use (e.g. to set text or some other property, which may only exists for that specific component).

Answer (score 1):

Note that a TextMeshProUGUI is a Component, not a GameObject. When you add a TextMeshProUGUI component it adds it to a new GameObject by default, which can be confusing. To make this more confusing, if you drag a GameObject into a Component slot, it will look for Components that match and add those directly.

If you have dragged the GameObject that contains the TextMeshProUGUI component in `bar` in the Editor, then you should just be able to set it with:

```
bar.SetText("bla");
```

Also note that you should use the `SetText()` method with the text mesh component instead of directly setting the `text` property.

Comment: I have expected `TextMeshProUGUI` to be an inherited from `GameObject` type. Thanks for clarifying, it was really helpful. Do you refer to [`text` performance](https://forum.unity.com/threads/textmeshpro-settext-vs-text-sometext-speed-test.926411/) in the last paragraph or do you mean something else? I would appreciate a link.

Comment: Looks like it is for a special case. The `SetText()` documentation says "You may wish to use this function instead of TextMeshPro.text if you need to concatenate a string with values and trying to avoid unnecessary garbage collection.". http://digitalnativestudios.com/textmeshpro/docs/ScriptReference/TextMeshPro-SetText.html
I always thought it was for historical reasons as setting Unity's `Text.text` property was the way to do this before TextMeshPro.

Comment: This may have changed after Unity acquisition as current Unity docs says they are the same: "This function is the same as using the text property to set the text." https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.textmeshpro@4.0/api/TMPro.TMP_Text.html

Comment: @GuneyOzsan Ah thanks, have to admit I haven't used TMP for a bit, so maybe this isn't such an issue now.

Answer (score 1):

Since you can add multiple components on a GameObject, there is no defined type for a GameObject (i.e. its type is already a GameObject). From there you can only try `GetComponent<>()` (or `GetComponent(s)InChildren<>()` for more complex objects) and see if there is one.

```
var textComponent = GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>();
if (textComponent != null) { // do something }
```

Or, you can use a serialized field and assign it manually from Unity editor, or automatically during `Awake()`.

About your question on the naming of TextMeshPro components, they use a specific attribute to display a different name in Editor (which I believe is an anti-pattern for Unity). If you check the `TextMeshProUGUI` source code you can see it there:

```
...
[AddComponentMenu("UI/TextMeshPro - Text (UI)", 11)]
...
public partial class TextMeshProUGUI : TMP_Text, ILayoutElement
{
    ...
{
```

`
For finding such type names conveniently, you can do a text search across the solution for the name you see in Unity editor (e.g. UI/TextMeshPro - Text (UI)) and see type names (e.g. TextMeshProUGUI) in source code instead of struggling around the documentation or web.

Comment: Aye, it seems I need to find the component type (as per @Chriss-Trott answer). Searching  in solution is a good hint thanks, I was hoping for a more "visual" way, similar to how visual studio property window typically shows the selected object type in various designers (wpf, winforms, ...). The official website didn't even find the said component when pressing (?) button in inspector. Should I've looked [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.textmeshpro@3.0/api/TMPro.TextMeshProUGUI.html)?

Comment: @Sinatr As I said this is quite an anti-pattern that I never saw any other developer using different names for Editor display and the class. You may never need to do a text search in solution ever again:) If I don't use TextMeshPro for a while I always struggle to guess which component was what. No, you shouldn't have looked at the docs because looking there assume you already know the type name, which is what you are looking for. It is a design fault from my perspective.